# Leaflet in combination with Leaflet.RotatedMarker

Tags: rotation, leaflet, leaflet.draw

i am using Leaflet in combination with Leaflet.RotatedMarker to add markers with rotation degrees.

The issue:

If i want to add my own icons like this:

> ```
> var marker =L.marker([x, y,z], {
> icon: car_n,rotationAngle: z }).addTo(map);
> ```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtPrl.png)

How can i only add my icon? Thx guys

Answer (score 0):

Okay it works fine...error was on calling the function.thx :)